# What are latest research in reverse engineering?

Tags: ida, windows, ollydbg, pe

I am searching research papers related to reverse engineering between 2020 and 2022 but did not found good papers with latest research in the direction of reverse engineering.
So, what are the latest research or technology in direction of reverse engineering?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. What about the tags you chose? Are you asking this question with a focus on the mentioned tools and platform? Also, I think this question is pretty much opinion-based, given that "latest research" is already a stretch term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be research, you just have to pick the right search terms.

For example, searching for `research paper binary analysis` led to "Proceedings 2021 Workshop on Binary Analysis Research".

You can also use the advanced search at ScienceGate to restrict the results by year - https://www.sciencegate.app/app/search